# Зависимость между тестами в разных классах

Tags: java, testng

Доброго дня!

Есть два класса, в одном классе есть Test1, во втором классе есть Test2. Можно ли между ними прокинуть зависимость (Что бы выполнение Test2 зависило от выполнение Test1)? Можно ли в dependsOnMethods указать на тест из другого класса?

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете так сделать только если будете использовать наследование, но есть одно условие вы в классе Test1 указываете класс и объекты этого класса, а в Test2 надо указать методы этих класса.

И насчет вашего метода, это сделать можно потому что будут разные классы(если нет зависимости между классами).